# Django Static image File Failed to load resource

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

**FIXED**
This was my solution, in the main programs urls.py I had to add these lines.

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

I have an model called Item within there I have an image field. I added an new item with an image to the database and tried loading it inside of my index template. However I dont get an image when I look at the console it says ("WEBSITENAME/site_media/items/image.jpg 404 (Not Found)")

I think the problem lies within the settings.py file but I cant figure out what exactly I did wrong here.

**index.html template**

```
{% load static %}
<div class="item" style="background-image: url('{{ item.img.url }}')">`
```

**Model.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', default='', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.name)
```

**Views.py**

```
def index(request):
    latestItems = Item.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:3][::-1]
    return render(request, 'webshop/index.html', {'latestItems' :latestItems})
```

**settings.py**

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'site_media/')
MEDIA_URL = 'site_media/'
```

Comment: I managed to fix it. I had to add these lines in the main urls.py file:          from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: Please keep in mind, to be safe, you might add:

  `if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Answer (score 1):

In your `settings.py`

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and read this [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/)

With the directory root structure that you have shown, I think the above setting should work. Have not tested it though. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Understanding the provided docs is quite hard for someone who is quite new to django like me. I tried the code but unfortunatly nothing has changed. I already had the STATIC_URL = '/static/' btw since I can load a css file perfectly fine.

Comment: 1. check static file link - put static folder any css and test like this {{ template/css.css}} or {{ }} ctl + space u should be see any blow if u linked fine

Comment: 2. check item - If the item exists, {{item.anyfeilds}} is displayed on your page

Comment: 3. check Syntax - maybe incorrect `"background-image: url('{{ item.img.url }}')"`

Comment: All of these are fine I load the text from item fine I just didnt show it in the example my bad.  I am also loading a css file from a folder called appname/static/css/style.css the syntax should be alright. the images from the database are stored outside the app though in the project root like this: projectroot/site_media/items/item.jpg

Answer (score 0):

you have:

```
upload_to='items'
```

but:

```
{{ item.img.url }}
```

should that be?

```
{{ items.img.url }}
```

Comment: upload_to='items' is a folder called items the item.img.url is the object item

Answer (score 0):

in settings.py:

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__ file __))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static"),
)